# How could I pass the SSL Server Test for my site with A Grade?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a virtual host site configured on two webservers with ELB as front facing. I have domain.bundle.crt and domain.key on my webservers under /etc/httpd/ssl. I have verified my site at ssllabs.com and got Grade B, so I went through the Criteria Categories through which the ssllabs gives the grade and got below values for my site

```
Protocol support: TLS 1.2   -  100%
Key exchange: 2048 key private key length  -  90%
Cipher Strength: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.128bit keys  -   80%
```

How could I improve the grade for my site from B to A.

I have followed the below guide as a part of troubleshooting

https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide

I have got the following result. What I need to do to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Do you use a custom security policy for ELB? Their current default `ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08` does not include any RC4 ciphers

Comment: So Do I need to disable the RC4 cipher. If yes then could you please let me know how could I disable it and will there be any problem to the site if I disable it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [OpenSSL Padding Oracle vulnerability with latest openssl 1.1.0c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330977/56041) on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). It gives you a configuration that is A+, and it includes protocol list, cipher list, and Strict-Transport-Security headers.